# Angularjs watch array and get changed object

Tags: angularjs

In the context of inserting or deleting from an array in angular, is it possible to watch the array and then get the object that was added or deleted from the array?  I don't care about the objects properties in the array, only the objects themselves being added or deleted.  So I believe $watchCollection is a good fit here so it's not a deep watch.

For example, I have this array as a model for a dual list box:

```
$scope.employees = [
    {
      name: "Bob",
      id: "0"
    },
    {
      name: "Carl",
      id: "1"
    },
    {
      name: "Bill",
      id: "2"
    }
  ];
```

The listbox will automatically update $scope.employees when i move one off of it or onto it (insert/delete).  If I do:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('employees', function(){
    //somehow get changed object
    var changedObject = ...;
    $scope.changedItems.push(changedObject);
  });
```

I want to be able to get the added/deleted item so I can use it or save it somewhere.

Comment: use the new and old values `$scope.$watchCollection('employees', function(newVal, oldVal)`

Comment: @Ronnie, don't those values contain the entire array objects?  Would I have to do a compare then to find the changed object?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there is an out of the box method of telling you which one changed. Perhaps you take care of that when you actually do the changing of the object rather than relying on a watch method.

Comment: @Ronnie, I would do that, however I'm using a [dual listbox directive](https://github.com/frapontillo/angular-bootstrap-duallistbox) and it doesn't seem to have any events I can hook onto for when it adds to the array in my model :(  I'll attempt the method of using newVal and oldVal, but I'm afraid it's going to get ugly with insert and delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$watchCollection` handler function receives both new and old value:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('employees', function(newValue, oldValue){
    console.log(newValue);
    console.log(oldValue);

    var addedArray = newValue.filter(x => !oldValue.find(x));
    var removedArray = oldValue.filter(x => !newValue.find(x));

    var changedObject = {added: addedArray, removed: removedArray};
    $scope.changedItems.push(changedObject);
  });
```

For more information, see [AngularJS $watchCollection API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection)